# Convert text to UTC timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have timestamp in text format in my table. It's of the following format `2019-05-30T05:48:29.095705642+01:00`. I want to convert this into UTC timestamp.

I am thinking of first converting text into timestamp and then converting it into UTC. I am executing `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-30T05:48:29.095705642+01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"')` but it doesn't work. I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For Milliseconds (`.MS`) you only can take 3 decimal digits. If you would use `.US` instead, you are able to cast 6 digits.

But if you do not want to strip the digits in an separate operation (and if you are sure that there are always 3 digits more) you can ignore them by adding the 9 pattern (`US999`). The result would be the same as use stripped it before.

[documentation (table 9.26)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-formatting.html)

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
        '2019-05-30T05:48:29.095705642+01:00', 
        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US999"Z"'
     )
```

---

But the most simple way - if you really have this date format - is the direct cast into timestamptz. PostgreSQL does the magic for you and there is no need to consider the number of decimal digits:

```
SELECT '2019-05-30T05:48:29.095705642+01:00'::timestamptz
```

---

After the cast from text to timestamp you can switch the timezone with `at time zone 'UTC'`:

```
SELECT '2019-05-30T05:48:29.095705642+01:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3dea297c48f566d81789ed6f5456ac23)

---

As stated in the comments: The time zone is not considered correctly. `"Z"` only ignored the letter Z. To parse the time zone you would need to write `TZH:TZM`. Another reason why you simply should use the PostgreSQL magic.

Comment: I have dates already stored in text. Is it a good idea to first format it to take milliseconds upto three decimal places and then convert ?

Comment: As well as the extra resolution of fractional seconds, the format pattern given looks like it won't match the timezone at the end properly: it's saying to ignore a single "Z", but the input actually ends "+01:00" (which maybe needs to be a variable match?).

Comment: @IMSoP I really missed this. My focus was on the digits. I added a part.